# Retrieve new item first from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
private void loadOrders(String phone) {

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
            Request.class,
              R.layout.order_layout,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            requests.orderByChild("phone")
                    .equalTo(phone)

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, final Request model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText("Order ID: "+adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText("Order Status: "+convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderAddress.setText("Address: "+model.getAddress());
            viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText("Phone Number: "+model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.txtOrderComment.setText("Order Note: "+model.getComment());
            viewHolder.txtOrderDate.setText("Order Date: "+Common.getDate(Long.parseLong(adapter.getRef(position).getKey())));
            viewHolder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        alertdialog(position);


                }
            });

            viewHolder.btnDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent orderDetail = new Intent(OrderStatus.this,OrderDetail.class);
                    Common.currentRequest=model;
                    Intent intent = orderDetail.putExtra("OrderId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(orderDetail);


                }
            });

            if((Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus())).equals("Delivered"))
            {
                viewHolder.btndelivered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                viewHolder.btn_delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }



        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

this is the code I'm using to retrieve orders from the database but it shows old orders first.how do I make it retrieve new orders first?

if I use ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setReverseLayout(true); it just displayes list upside down

[image]

Comment: sort them based on date?

Comment: @uneq95 suggest me how to do so i can store timestamp with order details.

Comment: Are you trying to list out orders related to a specific phone number?

Comment: Can you also tell which library you used for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: Can you try this - layoutmanager.setStackFromEnd(true);?

Comment: also could you post your database structure? it would be more clear then.

Comment: Hi @uneq95 thx for the solution

Comment: You should put the accepted solution, so that its beneficial to others too.